# Jquery Namespacing please

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have the below code in my plugin i know the arrangement is wrong.
i read that it is wrong to claim more than one namespace in the jQuery.fn object. 
please how do i do it correctly.
this is how i call it in my code

```
jQuery.fn.loadlink("shoping/loadsell.php?id="+id,"boxpostt"+id);
jQuery.fn.close(1500);


jQuery.fn.loadlink = function (urllink,divid) {
                        return $("#"+divid).load(urllink);
                    }

                    jQuery.fn.close = function (number) {
                        if(number==""){number = 0};
                        return setTimeout(function () {$('#lightBox, #lightBoxcontainer').remove();},number);
                    }

                    jQuery.fn.refresh = function (url) {
                        return window.parent.location.href = url;
                    }

                    jQuery.fn.center = function () {
                        this.css('position', 'fixed');
                        //var modalTop =  ($(window).height()/3) - (this.height());  
                        //var modalLeft = ($(window).width()/2) - (this.width()/2); 
                        var modalTop = ($(window).height() - this.height()) / 5;
                        var modalLeft = ($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft();


                        this.animate({
                            'left': modalLeft + 'px',
                            'top': modalTop + 'px'
                        });
                        return this;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks almost right, but remember that you need to define a function before you call it.
When do you define the variable id?

```
jQuery.fn.loadlink = function (urllink, divid) {
    return $("#" + divid).load(urllink);
};
jQuery.fn.close = function (number) {
    return setTimeout(function () {
        $('#lightBox, #lightBoxcontainer').remove();
    }, +number);
};
jQuery.fn.refresh = function (url) {
    return (window.parent.location.href = url);
};
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css('position', 'fixed');
    var modalTop = ($(window).height() - this.height()) / 5,
        modalLeft = ($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft();    
    this.animate({
        'left' : modalLeft + 'px',
        'top' : modalTop + 'px'
    });
    return this;
};
jQuery.fn.loadlink("shoping/loadsell.php?id=" + id, "boxpostt" + id);
jQuery.fn.close(1500);
```

Comment: jQuery.fn.loadlink("shoping/loadsell.php?id=" + id, "boxpostt" + id);
jQuery.fn.close(1500); is just how to use it you can remove the id jQuery.fn.loadlink("shoping/loadsell.php?id=1", "boxpostt");